Is initial condition provided enough to prove answer?

What I have done:

Here is my work:

$$\pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}} : a_{11} = 2a_{12} - 3a_{22}$$

Has zero vector?
 Letting $a_{12} = a_{22} = 0$ makes $a_{11} = 0$ and letting $a_{21}=0$ gives zero vector.
Closed addition?
$$A = \pmatrix{-1&1\\3&1} \text{ and } B = \pmatrix{-2&2\\1&2} \text{ then } A + B = \pmatrix{-3 & 3 \\ 4 & 3}$$
$$A = \pmatrix{0&3\\5&2} \text{ and } B = \pmatrix{13&2\\0&-3} \text{ then } A + B = \pmatrix{13 & 5 \\ 5 & -1}$$
Closed $\checkmark$
Scalar Multiplication?
$$A = \pmatrix{-1&1\\3&1} \text{ then $\alpha A$ can be } (\alpha = -2) \implies \pmatrix{2&-2\\-6&-2}$$
Closed $\checkmark$

So $S = \{(a_{ij} \mid a_{11} = 2a_{12} - 3a_{22}\}$ is a subspace.


My thought process:

At the beginning of my work, I established the condition $a_{11} = 2a_{12} - 3a_{22}$, which defines the set of matrices $S$. This condition is crucial, as it restricts all matrices in the set to satisfy this specific relationship. Because of this, any matrices I used as examples for verifying the subspace properties were inherently aligned with this constraint.
Due to the condition I provided, it was not necessary to use general variables when checking the three properties (zero vector, closure under addition, and closure under scalar multiplication). The constraint $a_{11} = 2a_{12} - 3a_{22}$ guarantees that any real numbers chosen for the entries of the matrices would conform to the condition automatically. Therefore, there is no selection of real numbers that would violate this constraint or invalidate the examples used to check the properties.
Here’s how I approached each condition:
Zero Vector: I showed that setting $a_{12} = a_{22} = 0$ results in $a_{11} = 0$, which proves that the zero matrix is part of the set.
Closed Under Addition: Using specific matrices A and B that satisfy the condition, I demonstrated that their sum also satisfies $a_{11} = 2a_{12} − 3a_{22}$, confirming closure under addition.
Closed Under Scalar Multiplication: I showed that multiplying a matrix by a scalar yields another matrix that satisfies the condition, ensuring closure under scalar multiplication.
By starting with this defined constraint at the top of the page, I ensured that all matrices, whether chosen as examples or represented by variables, must satisfy the condition $a_{11} = 2a_{12} - 3a_{22}$. As such, using variables was unnecessary because the examples I provided represent all possible outcomes within the set.

The issue:

I am being told that my initial condition, enumerated at the top of the page, is insufficient to prove that $S$ is a subspace and that an example is insufficient to justify this conclusion.
Am I wrong in my conclusion/thought process?

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You have to show closure under addition and under scalar multiplication for all such matrices, not just for some examples

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Before you tell us what you've done, what problem were you trying to solve?

The biggest issue is that you have shown examples of closure holding, but you have not shown closure. To show closure, under addition or scalar multiplication, you must prove a universal statement. To show closure under addition, say, you must show that for every possible pair of matrices in $S$, their sum is also in $S$. Picking two pairs of matrices from $S$, as you did, simply does not have the power to prove this statement about all pairs of matrices from $S$.
To demonstrate how this style of proof may fail, take, for example, the subset
$$S = \{(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : 0 \le x \le 1 \text{ and } 0 \le y \le 1\}.$$
This subset is a filled-in square on the Cartesian plane. Is it a subspace? No it's not. As a counterexample, we could choose, say
$$(0.7, 0.2), (0.6, 0.3) \in S,$$
and note that
$$(0.7, 0.2) + (0.6, 0.3) = (1.3, 0.5) \notin S,$$
because the $x$ coordinate is greater than $1$. Note that a single counterexample is sufficient; we have shown that not all pairs of vectors from $S$ will sum to vectors in $S$. The above is an example of at least one pair where closure under addition fails (and, naturally, there are many more examples).
However, it's perfectly possible to choose pairs of vectors from $S$ where their sum does indeed lie in $S$. I could correctly claim that:
\begin{align*}
&(0.2, 0.1), (0.4, 0) \in S, \text{ and } (0.2, 0.1) + (0.4, 0) = (0.6, 0.1) \in S \\
&(0.01, 0.9), (0.3, 0.1) \in S, \text{ and } (0.01, 0.9) + (0.3, 0.1) = (0.31, 1) \in S,
\end{align*}
but that's not a proof that it works all the time! Perhaps I just needed to look a little harder for counterexamples. And, given there are infinitely many pairs of vectors from $S$, there's no way for me to exhaust all possibilities by computing examples one at a time.
Instead, with your specific problem, start by assuming you have two matrices $\pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}}$ and $\pmatrix{b_{11} & b_{12} \\ b_{21} & b_{22}}$ that both belong in $S$. That is, you may assume
$$a_{11} = 2a_{12} - 3a_{22} \text { and } b_{11} = 2b_{12} - 3b_{22}.$$
What about the sum of the matrices
$$\pmatrix{a_{11} + b_{11} & a_{12} + b_{12} \\ a_{21} + b_{21} & a_{22} + b_{22}}?$$
Can you show it belongs to $S$? That is, can you show:
$$a_{11} + b_{11} = 2(a_{12} + b_{12}) - 3(a_{22} + b_{22})?$$
I'll leave it to you.
